# How to stream SoundCloud at a different speed or tempo?

Tags: soundcloud

From the [SoundCloud API Guide](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#playing), this is how to get the streaming URL of a sound:

```
import soundcloud
# create a client object with your app credentials
client = soundcloud.Client(client_id='YOUR_CLIENT_ID')

# fetch track to stream
track = client.get('/tracks/293')

# get the tracks streaming URL
stream_url = client.get(track.stream_url, allow_redirects=False)

# print the tracks stream URL
print stream_url.location
```

Is there any way to command the API to return a URL for the sound at a different speed or better yet, at a different [tempo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempo)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats not a feature from SoundClouds API. You need to somehow analyze your track to change the tempo / speed / bpm. For that you can use the EchoNest / Spotify APIs.

Check this question:

[How to get BPM and tempo audio features in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635063/how-to-get-bpm-tempo-audio-features-in-python)

If you change to JavaScript you can use the browser built-in WebAudio / WebMIDI API on Chrome and/or FireFox.

API description by Mozilla:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API

Examples by Google:

http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/

Hackday project based on Samplr + SoundCloud API using WebAudio + WebMIDI (Chrome only):

<strike>http: // dope-dj-culture.com/</strike> No longer a valid URL.